# Downgrade Website from Django 1.4 to Django 1.3

Tags: django

I have developed a website in Django 1.4 that I want to downgrade to 1.3 because I have a module that isn't compatible with 1.4, and the server already has Django 1.3 installed.  What do I have to go about doing to do this?  Thanks-

Comment: I would just run it and see where it blows up, and then work around it.

Comment: There are multiple areas that could be using 1.4 features. The settings, template, queries, views.

Comment: Downgrading is harder than upgrading for that matter. You can try it first and see how it goes. Depends a lot on the 1.4 features you used.

Comment: There are so many libraries which are incompatible with Django 1.4 :( I decided to downgrade too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go through [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/) for 1.4, especially the backwards incompatible changes, noting everything that is new in 1.4 and is being used in your project, and has to be changed first hand.

Then, if you have a test suite (which will help a lot in this case) run it against 1.3. If not, well, get at least minimal coverage, basically GET all your views in it, and run against 1.3. 
Else, like Ignacio said, just plug and pray :)

Answer (score 4):

Why are you not using virtualenv?

This would allow you to run this app with its own copy of django (1.4) without troubling the rest of the server.

Comment: I am using virtualenv!  I shoulda asked this question-- So if the rest of the server is running Django 1.3, can I just run a virtualenv in the app's directory and install Django 1.4 there?  Thanks-

Comment: Yes. This is exactly the objective.